# Import-Csv / Export-Csv with german umlauts (ä,ö,ü)

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, import-csv, export-csv

i came across a little issue when dealing with csv-exports which contains mutated vowels like ä,ö,ü (German Language Umlaute)

i simply export with

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$_;ID=4627} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Default -Force ("c:\temp\CSV_temp\"+ $_.basename + ".csv")
```

which works fine. i have the ä,ö,ü in my csv-file correctly.

after that i do a little sorting with:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp\*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { Import-Csv $_.FullName } |
    Sort-Object { [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.TimeCreated, $pattern, $culture) } |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\merged.csv' -Encoding Default -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

i played around with all encodings, ASCII, BigEndianUnicode, UniCode(s) with no success.

how can i preserve the special characters ä,ö,ü and others when exporting and sorting?

Comment: Make sure you supply the correct encoding to `Import-Csv` as well

Comment: Awesome, i simply missed the encoding at the inbound of the foreach import object. Thank you so much, it works perfectly.

Comment: The fundamental rule of character encodings is to read bytes that represent text with the same encoding that it was written with. `Default` varies from machine to machine, user to user and even time to time, so it is very rarely one that a writer would want to use.

Comment: @TomBlodget: In the (legacy) _Windows_ world, the default encoding varies by _culture_ and is set at the _machine_ level (the _Windows "ANSI" code page_, ACP).
While such an - unmarked - culture-dependent encoding is increasingly problematic, it is still very common,
and Windows PowerShell _in part_ defaults to it - notably with the basic `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` cmdlets; despite even naming the ACP
encoding `Default` when used with the `-Encoding` parameter, however, other cmdlets do _not_ use it by default, which is the truly problematic aspect here.

Comment: Sure it's troublesome when standard cmdlets don't have a consistent behavior. But, look at it this way: Since 1996, the Windows OS has used the Unicode character set. So, if your text source is the OS, such as via `Get-WinEvent`,  and you don't use a Unicode encoding, such as UTF-8, you potentially get silent data loss. So, one strategy is to just specify UTF-8 everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) provides the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

It is the `Import-Csv` call, not `Export-Csv`, that is the cause of the problem in your case:

**Like `Export-Csv`, `Import-Csv` too needs to be passed `-Encoding Default` in order to properly process text files encoded with the system's active "ANSI" legacy code page**, which is an 8-bit, single-byte character encoding such as Windows-1252.

**In *Windows PowerShell*, even though the generic text-file processing `Get-Content` / `Set-Content` cmdlet pair *defaults* to `Default` encoding (as the name suggests), regrettably and surprisingly, `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` do *not*.**

Note that on *reading* a default encoding is only assumed if the input file has *no BOM* (byte-order mark, a.k.a Unicode signature, a magic byte sequence at the start of the file that unambiguously identifies the file's encoding).

Not only do `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` have defaults that differ from `Get-Content` / `Set-Content`, they *individually* have different defaults:

- **`Import-Csv` defaults to UTF-8**.
- **`Export-Csv` defaults to ASCII(!)**, which means that any non-ASCII characters -such as `ä`, `ö`, `ü` - are transliterated to *literal* `?` chars., resulting in *loss of data*.

---

By contrast, in ***PowerShell Core***, the cross-platform edition built on .NET Core, the **default encoding is (BOM-less) *UTF-8*, consistently, across all cmdlets**, which greatly simplifies matters and makes it much easier to determine when you do need to use the `-Encoding` parameter.

---

#### Demonstration of the Windows PowerShell `Import-Csv` / `Export-Csv` behavior

**`Import-Csv`** - defaults to **UTF-8**:

```
# Sample CSV content.
$str = @'
Column1
aäöü
'@

# Write sample CSV file 't.csv' using UTF-8 encoding *without a BOM*
# (Note that this cannot be done with standard PowerShell cmdlets.)
$null = new-item -type file t.csv -Force
[io.file]::WriteAllLines((Convert-Path t.csv), $str)

# Use Import-Csv to read the file, which correctly preserves the UTF-8-encoded
# umlauts
Import-Csv .\t.csv
```

The above yields:

```
Column1
-------
aäöü
```

As you can see, the umlauts were correctly preserved.

By contrast, had the file been "ANSI"-encoded (`$str | Set-Content t.csv`; `-Encoding Default` implied), the umlauts would have gotten corrupted.

---

**`Export-Csv`** - defaults to **ASCII - risk of data loss**:

Building on the above example:

```
Import-Csv .\t.csv | Export-Csv .\t.new.csv
Get-Content .\t.new.csv
```

yields:

```
"Column1"
"a???"
```

As you can see, the umlauts were replaced by *literal question marks* (`?`).

Comment: *Export-Csv defaults to ASCII(!)* - insane, but true! Thanks for this detailed answer.

Comment: Yeah, @Andre, it's quite unfortunate; glad to hear the answer helped. Thankfully, _PowerShell (Core) 7+_ now uses UTF-8, _consistently_ across all cmdlets.